# wordpress custom search box for my new theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi friends  i am beginner for wordpress.i create a wordpress own theme for content management.daily add a new post in mysite.i want to see specific post.so i need a search box.create a search box  but not working in mysite.any one please help me i can't undestand this problem

my coding

searchform.php

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="search">
    <form role="search" method="get"  action="<?php echo home_url( '/'); ?>" id="searchform"> 
    <div class="search">
            <div class="input-group">                
                    <input class="form-control lg" id="inputdefault" placeholder="Search Mergosoft.com" type="search" value="" name="s">    
                  <span  id="search-btn-submit" class="btn lg btn-primary input-group-addon hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>                                  
                    <span class="btn xs btn-primary input-group-addon hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                                 </div>

                              </div>
                         </form>
                    </div>
```

search.php

```
enter code here
```

problem is i want to search type the input field and submit button page loading but can't get the result.loading after redirect to homepage.
mysite :https://www.mergosoft.com/

thanks for seeing my question

Comment: Is the `action=""` the correct url ? and please share the code block which retrieves the data

Comment: @Antonis Tsimourtos thanks for response. i can't understand

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a redirect from / to /en-in/. The

Template fails to load because/?s=test is being redirect to /en-in/?s=test

Try removing this redirect and see if the search template loads up.

Comment: thanks benedic sahagun for response. which php file  to change me direct index page open in my theme